# Google Drive APi and Google Maps in the same application

Tags: google-maps, google-drive-api

I'm using **Google Maps API** in my application. I want to use **Google Drive** too. Do I need to create a new key and project in google developer console, or just enable **Google Drive**?

Answer (score 1):

Just enabling Google Drive would be fine.

According to the console help docs:

> *a project* is a collection of settings, credentials, and metadata about the application or applications you're working on that make use of Google Developer APIs and Google Cloud resources.

So in other words, one project == one app.

https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/?hl=en_US#managing-projects-in-the-developers-console

Hope this help!

Comment: just to add to this correct answer, it is the array of scopes that you pass to OAuth that determines which APIs your app is granted access (of course, after you've configured such access in the API Console).